# Count having in a SELECT DISTINCT query?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

So I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.CITY, s.STATE, SUBSTR(s.ZIP,1,5) FROM table s
WHERE CITY IN (...)
AND STATE IN (...)
```

How would I add to this to only get count(s.ID) > 20 so I am only getting distinct city/state/zips that have above 20 IDs in the table?

I assume I need some sort of subquery, but I am unsure of how to accomplish it. Thank you.

Comment: Which database are you actually using - Oracle or MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the values you want to select and take only those groups having more than 20 records

```
SELECT s.CITY, s.STATE, SUBSTR(s.ZIP,1,5) 
FROM table s
WHERE CITY IN (...)
AND STATE IN (...)
GROUP BY s.CITY, s.STATE, SUBSTR(s.ZIP,1,5) 
HAVING count(*) > 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way using a subquery

```
SELECT s.CITY, s.STATE, SUBSTR(s.ZIP,1,5)
FROM Table S JOIN
(
  SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) Cnt
  FROM Table
  GROUP BY ID
) SS
ON S.ID = SS.ID
WHERE CITY IN (...)
AND STATE IN (...)
AND Cnt > 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `HAVING` if you need to filter on aggregates. `HAVING` is applied after grouping such as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.CITY, s.STATE, SUBSTR(s.ZIP,1,5), count(s.id) as count FROM table s
WHERE CITY IN (...)
AND STATE IN (...) 
GROUP BY s.CITY, s.STATE, SUBSTR(s.ZIP,1,5)
HAVING count > 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the HAVING clause:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html

I'm not exactly sure how it would work with your data.

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) FROM orders
  GROUP BY name
  HAVING COUNT(name) = 1;
```

Obviously you don't need to GROUP BY as you are selecting DISTINCT... So could be something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.CITY, s.STATE, SUBSTR(s.ZIP,1,5), COUNT(s.ID) FROM table s HAVING COUNT(s.ID) > 20
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @juergend The query might not be 100% what they need, however I believe the use of the HAVING clause is the/a correct solution to the issue. Which I notice you have used yourself. I have provided a link to the documentation along with a sample query from the documentation as a reference on how it can be implemented. This should give the asker the resources they need to create the correct query.

Comment: Yes, I use `HAVING`. I also use `SELECT`. That does not mean your query is correct because you have those words in your query. And you use it wrong. But thats fine by me. Good luck.

Comment: I mean, I never said the query was the solution, it's literally a sample query from the documentation. It's an example of using the `HAVING` clause...  Not sure what makes it that I am 'using it wrong', the query works when you run it, however I apologies it's not written by your hand...

However I do notice that since my above comment, 15:23, you, not edited, but remove and re-posted an answer at 16:00...? It's ok to accept feedback you know..

Comment: I did not remove and repost an answer. So I don't know what you mean. But anyway thats was a year ago. So I guess it does not matter.